# Custom taxonomy archive - No posts found

Tags: taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy 'quote-categories' (a separate category listing for a custom post type) and created a taxonomy-quote-categories.php template that is called successfully when viewing a taxonomy term.

However the page returns no matching post despite there being many posts in that category. I've called that content type successfully all around my site.

***FIXED***

The problem was the custom post type did not have the 'public' parameter set to 'true'. Otherwise it is invisible in normal loops and search results.

Comment: post your `taxonomy-quote-categories.php` code

Comment: Not necessary, I even copy/pasted a basic loop from Wordpress.org to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you must always go to the Page "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and refresh your permalink structure after you add both the Quote Post Type and the Category Taxonomy in your code, otherwise there is no regex with this pattern.

Here I've got this URL: http://localhost/quotes/category/dev

Because you've set the rewrite slug to "quotes/category". But about the file, it's correct should be this file. And make sure you are on the last version of WordPress, on 3.1 or something like it there was a problem on the Archives and 404s.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem was the post type did not have the 'Public' parameter set to 'true'. You're still getting a vote up :)