# Custom taxonomy - no posts found

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy, called "location", everything works fine, I can use it for labeling "open job position", but the problem occurs, when I try to access the archive or click on a taxonomy tag.

I have:

- reset the permalinks many times
- double checked the query
- double checked arguments
- seen this: [Custom taxonomy archive - No posts found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42788/custom-taxonomy-archive-no-posts-found) && [Custom Taxonomy returns no posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274293/custom-taxonomy-returns-no-posts)

Here is the code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_taxonomy_career' ) ) {

    // Register Custom Taxonomy
    function custom_taxonomy_career() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Locations', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Location', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Locations', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'foxconndrc' ),
            'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'foxconndrc' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'public'            => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,         
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'career_location' ),
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'career_location', array( 'career', 'post' ), $args );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_career', 0 );

}
```

Here is whole CPT with the code: https://pastebin.com/LqEkv0ZW

Comment: Are all `$labels` are essential in your question? And will somebody go to the third-party site to view your code? I see the general code you've published with no alterations. It's a standard. Rethink and edit.

Comment: @MaxYudin yes, it's general code, but somehow it seems that I can access archive from custom post type (even if there are no modifications), the issue is easy to replicate and even if I have asked colleagues we haven't found an answer.